# Detect if a vector2 is between two other vector2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

as the title suggests I am trying different ways but without solving.
I would need to check if the mouse is between two 2d points in PlayMode.
I thought of using **rect** to build a rectangle between two vector2 on the fly and check with **rect.contains** if the mouse position is inside the rectangle. This works if the rectangle is horizontal but the points on the screen are not aligned and it does not seem to me that there is a way to create an oblique rectangle.
I tried to calculate the **distance** between the two points, to create the rectangle and to move its **center** to rotate it but it doesn't seem to work. Also it seems that there is no way to display the rectangle on the screen and therefore it is difficult to understand if it retains its original shape after changing some parameters.
Do you have any suggestions? But I need the detection area to be rectangular and not on a single line. Using **LineCast** it is possible to solve but the detected area is too narrow.

I thought of a rectangle between the two vectors. Imagine a one-pixel line connecting the two vectors. Now increase the thickness of the line up to 10/20 pixels so that the mouse is detected a little before and a little after the original line. Maybe I'm wrong but I see the new rect as a good solution but as far as I looked at all its properties I can't understand how to build it between two vectors without too many lines of code.

Comment: What does it mean that the points on the screen are not aligned? It is always possible to build a rectangle between 2 2D points. If "not aligned" means that one is deeper than the other, just remove the depth component.

Comment: By "two points" I mean two Vector2. For example Vector2 (10,10) and Vector2 (50,50). I would need to detect when the mouse is on the line joining the two vectors. But the single line is very narrow and is difficult to detect by hovering over it. For this reason I thought of a rectangle. When I say that the points are not aligned I mean that they are not on the same y axis, the z axis is 0. I'm sure I'm wrong but how to build a new rect inclined from one vector2 to another vector2?

Comment: Find the distance from the mouse position to the line defined by your two points. If that distance is below some threshold, consider it to be "on the line."

Comment: The aim is to use this system as a collider. For this reason I thought of a rectangle between the two vectors. Imagine a one-pixel line connecting the two vectors. Now increase the thickness of the line up to 10/20 pixels so that the mouse is detected a little before and a little after the original line. Maybe I'm wrong but I see the new rect as a good solution but as far as I looked at all its properties I can't understand how to build it between two vectors without too many lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some vector math to:

1. Determine if the test point is not "outside" of the two points.
2. Calculate the distance from the line segment your point is, and if that's equal or below some threshold, then consider it to be "near" the segment between the two points.
3. If it's "near" the segment and not "outside" the two points, then consider it to be "between" the points.

For example:

```
Vector3 point1 = new Vector2(10f, 10f);
Vector3 point2 = new Vector2(50f, 50f);
float closeThreshold = 5f;

Vector3 testPoint = new Vector2(20f, 21f);

Vector3 segmentDirection = (point2-point1).normalized;
Vector3 point1ToTest = testPoint - point1;
Vector3 testToPoint2 = point2 - testPoint;

// determine if testPoint is not "outside" the points
if (       Vector3.Dot(segmentDirection, point1ToTest.normalized) >= 0f
        && Vector3.Dot(segmentDirection, testToPoint2.normalized) >= 0f)
{
    Vector3 closestPointOnSegment = point1 
            + segmentDirection * Vector3.Dot(point1ToTest, segmentDirection);

    // determine if testPoint is close enough to the line segment point1->point2
    if ((closestPointOnSegment - testPoint).magnitude <= closeThreshold)
    {
        // testPoint is "between" point1 and point2
    } 
}
```

This will work with `Vector3` or `Vector2`, which will safely convert to `Vector3` as shown above.

---

If you are only concerned with if the point is exactly between the two positions, take the directions from the point you're testing to either end of the line, and if the dot product between those directions is -1, then the point is between them:

```
Vector3 point1 = new Vector2(-1f,-1f);
Vector3 point2 = new Vector2(1f,1f);

Vector3 testPoint = new Vector2(0f,0f);

Vector3 testTo1 = (point1-testPoint).normalized;
Vector3 testTo2 = (point2-testPoint).normalized;

if (Mathf.Approximately(-1f, Vector3.Dot(testTo1, testTo2)))
{
    // testPoint is between point1 and point2
}
```

This will work with `Vector3` or `Vector2`, which will safely convert to `Vector3` as above.

Comment: Nice, but `testPoint` has to be pretty much exactly on the line for this to work. I'd add a fudge factor, like checking if the `.Dot` result is between `-0.9` and `-1`. (Since OP is using the mouse position as the test point, I imagine this is for selection / picking.)

Comment: Yes you are right, the aim is to use this system as a collider. For this reason I thought of a rectangle between the two vectors.

Comment: @3Dave Ah, I wrote this before asker clarified. Working with the `Dot` like that makes it lenient in different amounts between the points. I opted for a different solution. Please see update.

Comment: @3Dave I also missed the bit about the mouse position as input :)

Comment: Your original answer was cleaner. Really, all you needed was to check if the `Dot` result (`cos` of the angle between the vectors) was within, say, 10% of `-1`.

Comment: ... but now that I'm thinking about it, that could have some issues when the mouse is close to a segment endpoint. So, the new version may be a better answer. I'm not motivated enough to go test it. :)

Comment: @3Dave Yes, that's the idea - comparing the `Dot` like that makes it more lenient midway between the points than towards the ends. The new answer is an implementation of what you suggested in the question's comments